# WP_query Date Range results not matching loop

Tags: wp-query

I have written a WP_query with a date range.

```
            $args = array( 
                'date_query' => array( 
                    array(
                        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                        'after' => array('year' => $after[0], 'month' => $after[1], 'day' => $after[2])
                    ),
                    array (
                        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                        'before' => array('year' => $before[0], 'month' => $before[1], 'day' => $before[2])
                    )
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'inclusive' => false,
            );

            $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

which works perfectly when I output the sql and run it in phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_posts.post_date_gmt > '2015-01-11 23:59:59' 
AND wp_posts.post_date_gmt < '2015-01-17 00:00:00' ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

However the loop prints out more posts

```
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : 
   while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
```

I have tried using the reset loop functions but with no luck.  What am I doing wrong.  This is in a page template that is trying to mimic archive.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Try to dump the whole `$posts` object and see what's going on there.

Comment: The whole posts object shows the additional posts.   http://davies-barnard.uk/newsletters/   Pick the 2015/01/17 and click go. You'll see no. of posts returned as 3 but not in posts.

Comment: This is highly peculiar. You got 3 `found_posts`, but 11 `posts_count`, this seems plain invalid. There can't be more results than there can possibly be results. Is anything else at all possibly manipulating the `$posts` variable? Can you try this with plugins disabled.

Comment: Will do.   Does it make any difference for a WP Network?   (Thanks again!)

Comment: No change - I just disabled the plugins. I'm glad you are also surprised!   Would it make any difference that this is a page template pretending to be a weekly archive?

Comment: Ok,  its clearly adding the posts to the end of something.  The last three posts on the example are what I would expect.   I just need to clear the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run your query with

```
"suppress_filters" => true
```

`WP_Query` allows for posts to be added after the query has run. found_posts is the actual queried amount of posts, post_count is updated after running the filters.

If this fixes it search your code (Any active code, check network activated plugins as well) for `the_posts` or `posts_results` filter and check if that is causing it.

Another reason for this could be sticky posts as we discovered in the comments, these can be disabled using

```
"ignore_sticky_posts" => true
```

By default WP_Query adds sticky posts to the first page of archives where `is_home()` is true.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the response.   I have added both suppress filters ... and outputted the post count, which is 3 vs 11.   Sadly it has NOT fixed the problem :(

Comment: The posts it is adding are all those stickies from the homepage.  Is it adding these to every query?

Comment: Oh yeah, sticky posts, never use them ;).

You can remove them using ignore_sticky_posts => true

Comment: You are a LEGEND!!!    Love stickies except when they waste an evening of my life that could have been spent with my wife.  BIG THANKS!

Comment: I'll add it to my answer.